# How can I allow visitors to place marks on a diagram using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image, drawing, xpages, lotus-domino

I am working on a new XPages application (on a Domino server) that uses the Bootstrap framework to present a responsive web page. Most of the work I'm doing is pretty basic, and I've used the techniques before.

However, the application calls for a facility whereby the visitor has the ability to place marks on a fixed image. For instance, on an motor vehicle accident claim form, the claimant is asked to indicate on a diagram where the damage occurred...

[image: motor vehicle accident claim example]

I'd like to present a static image, and allow visitors to place indicators ontop of that image. I'd then like to save the resulting image somehow. If I can't save a consolidated image, I'd like the ability to save the coordinates of the visitor's indicators so that I can simulate the same marked-up diagram in the back end.

Is there a plug-in or documented technique somewhere that I can use to accomplish this, or shall I attempt to 'roll my own'? I haven't been able to find anything that accomplishes something like this.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this one!!

Comment: I don't know of a bootstrap plugin, but you could take a look at Annotorious

Comment: to save the image with annotations (as a new image) you should be easily able to roll your own using html5 canvas element to render the image and annotation(s), then saving content as a new image.

Comment: also if you roll your own consider using <svg> element because each 'shape' is a dom element and easy to add / remove shapes. I think you can take the contents of svg and save as a svg file as well

Answer (score 1):

Open the image in a canvas and let the user draw on the canvas. After this save the new image back to Domino.
http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/category/canvas-element

Answer (score 0):

Here is some jQuery code I have that will detect the coordinates of the moue click(s):

```
var locations = [];
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#yourImageId").click(function(e){
        var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        var obj = {x: relX, y:relY};
        locations.push(obj);
    });

}
```

You will now have a global array with the coordinates of all clicks. You can store it into the database, and then use it to put markers on the image at a later point.